# Is is possible to change the date format of the LastLoginDate in the aspnet_membership table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, membership

In the current project I'm working the initial developer had used ASP.NET Membership to handle the user login validation. As such the LastLoginDate and the LastActivityDate in the aspnet_Membership table are save in UTC format.

Is there anyway to save it in the local time format? Or does anyone know which stored procedure could be modified to compensate for the time difference (by using the DATEADD() method)?

Answer (score 1):

`aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo` is the Sp which update the `LastLoginDate`. You can modify this SP and cast the data format according to your requirement.

Comment: So I added the following to the stored procedure:

`DECLARE @AdjustedLastLoginDate datetime
SET @AdjustedLastLoginDate = (SELECT DATEADD(hour, 5, @LastLoginDate))
SET @AdjustedLastLoginDate = (SELECT DATEADD(minute, 30, @AdjustedLastLoginDate))`

and called the variable in the existing UPDATE method for the aspnet_membership table in the SP but the time is still save in UTC

Answer (score 1):

I would caution against changing the data from UTC to local time.

`SqlMembershipProvider` returns `MembershipUser.LastLoginDate` and other similar properties in local time: i.e. it converts the database value from UTC to local.

So if you're accessing this data via the `Membership` API, you don't need to do this.

If you're accessing the data in the database directly, and you really, really want SQL Server to return it in local time, why not just convert it when you're reading from the database.

For example, you could create a VIEW on the aspnet_Membership table something like:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    LastLoginDate + GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE() AS LastLoginDateLocal
    ...
FROM aspnet_Membership
```

Note that by doing the conversion in SQL Server, you'll be getting the local time of the SQL Server, which may not be the same as the local time on the machine hosting your application.

**UPDATE**

From comments:

> I want to know why @Leo approach didn't work.

@Leo suggested modifying the `aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo` SP; you need to modify all SPs that update the columns you're interested in.  For example, `LastLoginDate` is also updated by `aspnet_Membership_UpdateUser`.

Also, if you follow this approach, the time returned in `MembershipUser.LastLoginDate` property will be incorrect, since the `SqlMembershipProvider` code assumes the database value is in UTC.  To correct this problem, you would need to modify all the Membership SPs that SELECT this column, to convert back to UTC.  E.g. `aspnet_Membership_GetAllUsers`, `aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByEmail`, `aspnet_Membership_FindUsersByName`, ...

Note also that converting between UTC and local in SQL Server as above will sometimes give incorrect values (+/- 1h) due to DST (e.g. the difference GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE() is calculated during a period when DST is in operation, but the user last logged in before DST started).

Another reason why it's better to leave the database value in UTC, and do any conversion in your application.

Comment: Thanks @Joe this is an interesting approach. Since I already know what the time difference is going to be I simply called the LastLoginDate column as `DATEADD(hour, 5, DATEADD(minute, 30, dbo.aspnet_Membership.LastLoginDate)) AS LastLoginDate` and I got the adjusted time via the view. I wouldn't be marking your answer as the accepted answer just yet though; I want to know why @Leo approach didn't work.

Comment: I reflected the change in the following SPs:

aspnet_Membership_CreateUser,
aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword,
aspnet_Membership_SetPassword,
aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo,
aspnet_Membership_UpdateUser

but it still didn't work. The reason I'm trying to do it at a database level is because these values won't be retrieve via the application. Users (db admins) will have to look at the DB itself to get the values so having it in UTC might cause a bit of confusion.